# Vectorization of two for-loops

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize a function and I'm almost there. All that's left is this

```
for x in range(0,img.shape[1]):
        for y in range(0,img.shape[0]):  

            if w00[y,x] > 0:
                total[y,x] += img.item((y0[y,x], x0[y,x])) * w00[y,x]
            if w01[y,x] > 0:
                total[y,x] += img.item((y1[y,x], x0[y,x])) * w01[y,x]
            if w10[y,x] > 0:
                total[y,x] += img.item((y0[y,x], x1[y,x])) * w10[y,x]
            if w11[y,x] > 0:
                total[y,x] += img.item((y1[y,x], x1[y,x])) * w11[y,x]
```

This now looks very ugly as I vectorized everything else already and introduce this for-loop to not break the code. I struggle to vectorize this part as the indexes switch every time. Some help would be nice.

Also y1 and x1 are just x0 + 1 and y0 + 1, which could simplify vectorization

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
for w, x, y in zip([w00,w01,w10,w11], [y0,y1,y0,y1], [x0,x0,x1,x1]):
    total += img[y,x] * w * (w>0)
```

**Edit**: Some modification might be needed. I can't test whether the code runs properly due to lack of sample data.

Comment: But that's not vectorization xD
The idea is not to use a for loop and purely use array operations

Comment: It **is** vectorization. The point is you don't loop over `range(img.shape[0])` and `range(img.shape[1])`.

Comment: Well I don't want to use a for loop just pure array operations, that's my definition of vectorization. I'm not sure if my definition is strictly 100% correct, but that is how I learned it

Comment: My two cents, vectorization does not mean *no for loop* and *no for loop* does not mean vectorization. You can take it or not.

Comment: I don't see a speed increase with your solution, it's just written nicer

Comment: @sebko_iic Note that the loop in this solution only iterates four times, which corresponds to the number of variables you are considering. You can just replace it with `total += img[y0, x0] * w00 * (w00>0); total += img[y1, x0] * w01 * (w01>0); total += img[y0, x1] * w10 * (w10>0); total += img[y1, x1] * w11 * (w11>0);` if you don't want the loop. Whether or not is faster will depend on the data, but for any relatively large `img` array your double loop will most definitely be quite slower.